# How to upload photos in Instagram and share it to Foursquare from PC

Tags: instagram, foursquare

I am trying to find a way to upload a photo in Instagram and share it to Foursquare from my PC instead of my smartphone.

I am able to do it individually somehow, but I want to do it just like I am doing it in my smartphone.

I can check in and upload an image to foursquare using *Foursquare Photo Uploader*, which works like a charm. To upload an image in Instagram I can use *Gramblr* but it's available only in Windows and Mac and I am running Linux so I cannot do it individually.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a good answer for you because the services I use are "coming soon" to OSX but, I use grambler but I'm on PC, however, what I used to do what use a push service/app with my PC and smartphone. Just pushed the image I wanted to post to my smartphone and posted it to Instagram.